# What is the best algorithm to use in creating binary trees?

Tags: binary-tree, algorithm

I've been doing a research about the best algorithm to use in creating a binary tree implementation. THe top entry in my list is **nested sets**. Are there any other alternative or better algorithm??

If possible can you give me a list of top algorithms so that I can research/study it and see if it will fit the system needs.

Comment: @Javier - yep, but I'm looking for tree algo. The system is actually a multi level marketing type.

Comment: why dont u search some implementations over google. you are using the term "Algorithm" wrong. you are looking for a data structure, not an algorithm.

Comment: "Best" is such a wonderful term when describing data structures.  Does it scale?  What size datasets?  Do you need it to not change memory locations?  Better for insertions, max, min, deletions, control flow...?  Should it be sorted?  Are you sure a tree is what you really, really need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, it depends on what you are going to use it for.

- Is it important to do insertions, updates and/or deletes fast?
- Will you any specific out-of-the-ordinary operations on the tree?
- How much data will there be in the tree?
- Do you have to store it in a database or just in memory?

And so on..

For example, using a nested set is not really a good choice if the most important operation is: "given a node, find it's grandfather".

Also, you could leverage the fact that you want a binary tree. The nested set model can be used to describe any tree and doesn't really use the fact that it's binary.

Comment: Yup, I'm actually looking for list suggetions so that I can study the algorithm and determine the best fit.